# CSS text hiding behind image when trying to overlay on image

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Basically, all I was trying to is lay some text over an image on a website that I am making. I read online that I could do that by using position absolute and relative and it worked to some degree. The only problem is not my text is hiding under the image but I want it to be over the image.

```
.lol__header {
    display: flex;
}

.lol__header-content {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-right: 5rem;
    position: relative;
}

.lol__header-content h1 {
   font-family: var(--font-family);
   font-weight: 800; 
   line-height: 62px;
   letter-spacing: -0.04rem;
   position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 15%;
}

.lol__header-image {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.lol__header-image img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

React code:

```
const Header = () => {
  return (
    <div className="lol__ section__padding" id="home">
      <div className="lol__header-content">
        <h1 className="gradient__text">
          {" "}
          Labor of Love International Ministries
        </h1>
        <div className="lol__header-image">
          <img
            src={frontPage}
            alt="image of Pastor Wayne Preaching"
          ></img>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post your HTML so that we can see what’s wrong.

Comment: Add z-index:1 to the .lol_header-content h1 class. Or, place that element above the background element in the html.

Comment: I added the code it's react so it's jsx but hopefully that helps.

Comment: Since this is more somewhat about the CSS and render perhaps post a minimal set of HTML as it is rendered to work from as well as note any CSS libraries you may have in play here for example if you are using Bootstrap or something similar including any version iformation of those.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `z-index: 1` to `lol__header-content h1` like below.

```
.lol__header-content h1 {
  font-family: var(--font-family);
  font-weight: 800; 
  line-height: 62px;
  letter-spacing: -0.04rem;
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 15%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Also you can rearrange your HTML file and place your text after the image.

Thanks and best regards!

Comment: Hey, I did actually try the z-index but that did not seem to help I added the react code if that helps.